# Virtual Host for wamp server running in port 85

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

We have dedicated windows server where IIS running in :80 and Wamp running in :85. 
I successfully created a Virtual Host for wamp server which is running in :85.

```
NameVirtualHost *:85

<VirtualHost *:85>
ServerName www.my.tv
ServerAlias my.tv
DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/alpha
ErrorLog "C:/wamp/www/alpha/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "C:/wamp/www/alpha/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

yes the above code is working & site is running only when i hit **`www.my.tv:85`** but not in **`www.my.tv`**

can someone advice on the above where i could configure to make the site run at **`www.my.tv`**

Comment: When you don't enter a port number, :80 is the default. If you already have something else running on port 80, there's no way to do this.

Comment: If you want to use php why not serve it through iis

Comment: @Pekka but i found the same www.my.tv was running a site in IIS in port 80 before creating this. should i delete it? may be its block since its stopped.

Comment: So you have stopped IIS? THen you need to tell Apache to listen on port 80 instead of 85

Comment: @Pekka웃 NO. I haven't stopped IIS

Comment: So what do you want to see on www.my.tv: the Apache site, or the IIS site?

Comment: If IIS is running on port 80, you need to remove that first and then tell Apache to run on that port. Only one server can listen on a port at a given time.

Comment: consider if 4 virtual host are running IIS ar :80, if i change the IIS to run in port 85, does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure Apache to serve your site on port 85 then the browser (which will default to port 80) won't find it unless you give it the port number it needs.

If you need to see the site on port 80 then you need to configure it on that port. Since you have another server running on that port it's not an option.

One possibility is that you create a virtual site on your IIS server for `www.my.tv`, but have it redirect to the site on port 85. You can do this in the properties box, on the *Home Directory* tab.

Comment: Does IIS not have a proxy option as well?  I haven't used it in awhile... I would assume it does by now?

Comment: Prevsly www.my.tv was running in IIS server at port 80. i have stopped it & started creating a host in apache. does it affect?

Comment: @Parthi04 Use that site, select it from the IIS manager and in the properties box, Home directory tab, set the conetnt to come from a Redirect. Put the URL including the port number in as the redirect URL

Comment: @Brad no idea - I'm a bit rusty on IIS, but I did this for a Squeezebox server on my home network. Works a treat.